# Importing JS module in TS file

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

In Visual Studio Code, when there are two `.js` module files `A.js` `and B.js`, importing module A inside module B allows us to use autocomplete on imported module. When importing module A into `C.ts` this autocomplete is not available and ofcourse message appears `Could not find a declaration file for module <PATH_TO_A_MODULE>`. I saw answers that suggest creating declaration files for module A, but I want to avoid this because VS Code already "knows" declarations since it is working when importing JS module into another JS module. Environment is nodejs.

Example:

```
// A.js
export const some_variable = 1

// B.js
import * as A from 'A.js'
A.some_variable --> autosugestion and complete works

// C.ts
import * as A from 'A.js' --> this shows warning and autocomplete not available on A.
A.some_variable --> does not throw error but autocomplete is not working
```

Is there a way to allow importing JS modules into TS files without declaration files so that autocompleting and typing is working?

EDIT: (tsconfig.json)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": ".build",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    },
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your tsconfig.json like? Did you set the flag "allowJs"?

Comment: I just added tsconfig.json. I tried adding allowJS but problem persists. Code works perfectly well, there is no error in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you need to add typings for this for importing js module in TypeScript please read this : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

Comment: I have read it and I know how declaration files work, it is just weird to me that when importing .js module into another .js module, declarations are known without declaration file but importing .js module into .ts file disables autocomplete and IntelliSense in VS Code

Comment: that's because of your tsconfig file , you should update it then it will import js file also .

Comment: Which setting are you referring to?

Comment: {allowjs:true} in your tsconfig .

Comment: {
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",    
   "module": "es6"
   }

}

try this .

Comment: use es6 module in tsconfig instead of commonjs